# How to fix rule links for sonarqube comments on GitHub pull requests

Tags: github, sonarqube, teamcity, pull-request

I have a Team City build process that triggers a Sonarqube scan for every new pull request.  When the sonarqube scan finds issues, it creates pull request comments that list a reference to the rule in question.  But when I click those rule links, they don't point to my Sonarqube server and instead take me to the **nemo.sonarqube.org** domain, which doesn't actually work and doesn't display the issue description/help.  For example, they point to:

```
http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=Web%3AItemTagNotWithinContainerTagCheck
```

...instead of my own sonarqube server.  I want this link to send me to

```
http://my-domain.com/coding_rules#rule_key=Web%3AItemTagNotWithinContainerTagCheck
```

[image]

I didn't set all this up and don't know where this is configured, but I believe it is possible to make those links go to my own server.  At least I know they've worked in the past and has led to more detailed info on the rule.

Where is that configured?